# Azure Service bus Queue creation in C# does not set EnablePartioning or size?

Tags: c#, azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

I have the code below for creating a queue in Azure service Bus

```
        var cs = azureServiceBusConnectionString;
        var namespaceManager = NamespaceManager.CreateFromConnectionString(cs);
        if (namespaceManager.QueueExists(queueName))
        {
            namespaceManager.DeleteQueue(queueName);
        }

        var que = namespaceManager.CreateQueue(queueName);
        que.EnablePartitioning = true;
```

My queue is created ok but I have 2 questions

1) Even though I set EnablePartioning to true my queue has EnablePartioning set to false.  Why is this?  Is there a method I have to call to save the changes or something
2) I cant set the size of the queue as the SizeInBytes property is read only.  How can I do that?

I dont see any constructor that allows me to set EnablePartitioning or the size?

Paul

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should enable partitioning on a `QueueDescription` when creating the queue.

```
var cs = azureServiceBusConnectionString;
var namespaceManager = NamespaceManager.CreateFromConnectionString(cs);
if (namespaceManager.QueueExists(queueName))
{
    namespaceManager.DeleteQueue(queueName);
}

var queueDescription = new QueueDescription(queueName);
queueDescription.EnablePartitioning = true;
queueDescription.MaxSizeInMegabytes = 1024;

var que = namespaceManager.CreateQueue(queueDescription);
```

You cannot set `SizeInBytes` because it is based on the number and size of messages in the queue. It wouldn't make any sense to set it.

You can set the maximum queue size using the `MaxSizeInMegabytes` property.

Comment: Ok thanks I was meaning in azure they allow you to see the size in gb

Comment: You're probably thinking of the `MaxSizeInMegabytes` property.

Comment: Hmm thats strange the max size column still shows 16GB? Is that because of the partitioning?

Comment: The default number of partitions is 16. [Partitioned queues and topics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-partitioning#standard)

Comment: Ok thanks hopefully there is no cost implication to this i guess we billed by the number of messages and their size rather than the queue max size